# How can I update TFS 2013: Error TF246091

Tags: tfs

I am trying to copy a project collection from one team's TFS 2013 to mine. When attaching the project collection, I run the verify command. I get this error: 
TF246091: The team project collection cannot be attached because its version ID is higher than the ID for the configuration database. The collection has the following version: Dev12.M62. The Team Foundation Server is at the following version: Dev12.M53.

Digging around nets me zero. I tried the TfsConfig updates /reapply without anything being done. I downloaded the VS 2013 update 4 as this seems to be the only 'update' with TFS in mind. There simply isn't anything that I could find on a TFS server update. I even dug through MSDN subscriber downloads for any sort of update. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev12.M62 is TFS 2013 Update 2. Dev12.M53 is an earlier version (obviously).

You can download TFS 2013 Update 2 from MSDN and do an upgrade install, which should let you reattach the team project collection.

Or, better yet, just upgrade both instances to the latest version ([TFS 2013 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44911)).

Comment: Thanks. I found that right away, and downloaded it.. But it's the whole TFS server. When I mounted the iso and ran it, it started to install a new TFS instance, complaining of a prior instance. So, you're saying I just need to move forward with the install and there will be a prompt in there for an upgrade path and NOT a fresh install?

Comment: Correct, just install Update 4. It will remove the old version and install the new one. After the install the config will run and allow you to upgrade the database.

Comment: Well, I upgraded it. During the upgrading of the each of the features. the machine bounced itself. When it came back up, TFS is there, but ALL of the configuration is missing. It's as though I have a brand new TFS. Total, complete disaster

Comment: That's how the TFS upgrade process works: After you install, you have to point it to the configuration database. It then detects that the configuration database is on a previous version, and upgrades it.

Comment: Daniel. I panicked. It's fine. After the arbitrary self reboot, I didn't see the 'upgrade' option. All is well. I owe you a beer !